# Por que quando eu digito a nova o novo exame ele continua a fazer a soma do exame novo com a média do velho?

Tags: php

A Questão é essa em php:
Ler quatro valores referentes a quatro notas escolares de um aluno e imprimir uma mensagem dizendo que o aluno foi aprovado, se o valor da média escolar for maior ou igual a 7. Se o valor da média for menor que 7, solicitar a nota de exame, somar com o valor da média e obter nova média. Se a nova média for maior ou igual a 5, apresentar uma mensagem dizendo que o aluno foi aprovado em exame. Se o aluno não foi aprovado, indicar uma mensagem informando esta condição. Apresentar junto com as mensagens o valor da média do aluno para qualquer condição.

esse é o formulário principal:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Questões</title>
<body>
<form action="q6php.php" method="POST">
 Digite a primeira nota: <input type="number" name="n1"><br>
 Digite a segunda nota: <input type="number" name="n2"><br>
 Digite a terceira nota: <input type="number" name="n3"><br>
 Digite a quarta nota: <input type="number" name="n4"><br>
 <input type="submit" value="Salvar" name="menu">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Esse é o php:

```
<?php
$n1 = $_POST['n1'];
$n2 = $_POST['n2'];
$n3 = $_POST['n3'];
$n4 = $_POST['n4'];
$med = (($n1+$n2+$n3+$n4)/4);
if($med>=7){
      echo("aprovado com ". $med);
    }else if($med<7){
    header('location: q6formdir.php');
    $k= $_POST['n5'];
    if(isset($_POST['salvar'])){
       $mednova = (($med + $k)/2);
      if($mednova>=5){
      echo("aprovado em exame com ".$mednova);

}else{
      echo("reprovado");
}
}

    }

?>
```

e esse outro é o formulário que se a média for menor que 7 ele vai pedir outro teste:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Questões</title>
<body>
<form action="q6php.php" method="POST">
  Digite a nota do novo exame: <input type="number" name="n5">
  <input type="submit" value="salvar" name="salvar">
  <input type="hidden" value="n1" name="n1">
  <input type="hidden" value="n2" name="n2">
  <input type="hidden" value="n3" name="n3">
  <input type="hidden" value="n4" name="n4">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Não entendi a pergunta. Quando você digita o que?

Comment: Seus campos hidden não estão servindo pra nada. Eles não vão pegar magicamente as notas já existentes. Pra facilitar, o formulário também tem que ser em PHP (o que te ajudaria a ter um formulário só pras duas situações).

Answer (score 0):

Não vejo o porque usar dois formulários para a mesma função, basta retornar ultilizando o `header('Location');`.

```
   $med = (($n1+$n2+$n3+$n4)/4);

     if($med>=7){
        echo("aprovado com ". $med);
     }else if($med<7){
        header('location: q6formdir.php');

     $k= $_POST['n5'];

     if(isset($_POST['salvar'])){
        $mednova = (($med + $k)/2);
     if($mednova>=5){
     echo("aprovado em exame com ".$mednova);
     }else{
    echo("Reprovado, Faça outro teste!");
    header('Location: exame.php');
   //retorna ao formulario;
    }
   }
 }

?>
```